# Wrong links in Wordpress?

Tags: php, urls

I have a project on Wordpress. I would like add an article. 
In admin panel I click on **Post**, then **Categories** and add a new category called **article**.

Next I add a new post and edit title, body and finally check the category called **article**. 
Now i have:

> Permalink: http://mypage.org/article/test

On site also is this link, but if I open this url I have:

> This entry was posted in **article**. Bookmark the permalink. Follow
>   any comments here with the RSS feed for this post. Post a comment or
>   leave a trackback: Trackback URL. Edit

But in this url I don't have my article. Why? In index page I have it, but if I open an article I have this error.

What can I do?

Comment: Did you click on the blue button «Publish»?

Comment: yes, of course. All articles are on page, but links are wrong

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings, then General Settings, then enter the correct url for your Wordpress Address (URL). Perhaps you need to change your Site Address too.

Source: The Wordpress Codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_General_Screen

If this isn't the case, but the category links are bad, edit the category slug. Go to Posts, then Categories, select **article** and edit the slug. Perhaps you had a different slug beforehand.

It's difficult to help you. It's a game of guessing. I will stop here.

Comment: i have there correct url. Others links on pare are good, only in articles is bad.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's a category problem, isn't it?

Comment: yes, this is problem with links to post in categories